# GitLab Docker build locked on sharp download (timeout)

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab-ci, npm-install, sharp

During Docker build in Gitlab job pipeline the process is freezed on

> - sharp@0.28.3 install /app/node_modules/sharp
> - (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
> - sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.6/libvips-8.10.6-linux-x64.tar.br

**After 1 hour buil is killed by timeout.**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.17.0

WORKDIR /app

ARG NODE_ENV=dev

ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

ENV PORT 3005

COPY ["package.json", "tsconfig.json", "./"]

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./views ./views
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I tryed build docker on my Windows environment whitout problem.

Comment: i had the same issue on my macos, docker process killed while downloading sharp module. I increased docker resources(2 GB RAM and 2 GB swap memory) and next time this issue got fixed.  @Pid, in your case, try to use larger gitlab runner.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [`lovell/sharp` issue 2611](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2611#issuecomment-827633532)

Workaround:

> In case you cannot upgrade, change this line in `node_modules/sharp/binding.gyp`:
>
> ```
> '-std=c++0x',
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> '-std=c++14',
> ```
>
> And run npm rebuild

Actual solution: upgrade.

> I force the resolution on `package.json` to use the new version of Sharp and I could install and run, however my node-sass blow due the Node 16.
> I remove the sharp resolution and downgrade the image in the gitlab CI Docker to node:14
>
> Everything works fine now, so it seems was an issue with Node instead of Sharp.

---

The [OP Pid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10105024/pid) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495033/gitlab-docker-build-locked-on-sharp-download-timeout/68495194#comment121064974_68495194) having resolved the issue by updating the host OS Ubuntu (20.04).
But that lead to [lovell/sharp issue 2817](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2817), which in turn requires  GitLab support.

Comment: i have resolved issue, i have update the system (Ubuntu 20.04) where Kubernetes cluster running.

Comment: @Pid Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The problem isn't resolved. This is a debug: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2817

Comment: @Pid OK. I have updated the answer accordingly.